# File not getting sent to controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to open a form which will take in a picture (from the camera) and than send it to my controller in laravel.

Does any body know why this is not working?

Form in laravel:

```
    <div style="width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
   {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'upload_photo', 'files' => true)) }}
      <input type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" id="camera_input" name="camera_input" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />             
</div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg normal-font" type="button" onclick="takePicture();">Take Picture And Upload</button>
   {{ Form::close(); }}
```

Javascript which will simply just open the camera/file select on click:

```
function takePicture() {
   document.getElementById("camera_input").click();
}
```

Laravel controller:
All I am doing is this to try to see if the file gets put over here:

```
   public function upload_photo() {
      $file = Input::file('camera_input');
      var_dump($file);
   }
```

It is getting NULL printed out for $file though...
Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does manually clicking the input, selecting an image, and submitting the form work?

Comment: It works but it gets NULL printed out when it goes to the 'upload_photo' route from the $file variable so I think its not actually working?

Answer (score 0):

I got it apparently my input type needed:
enctype="multipart/form-data"

I thought have files => true on the form for laravel would do this and thats what that was for but apparently it needed to be on the input type.
Maybe because I didnt use laravel's Form::file()